# R least sqaure regression, residuals is in date format

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
security<-"NFLX"
startDate<-"2012-06-01"
endDate<-"2016-10-31"
qte_list<-c("AdjClose")

data=get.hist.quote(instrument = security, startDate, endDate, quote = qte_list,   provider = "yahoo" )
head(data[,1])
rt<-diff(log(data[,1]))
class(rt) #this is zoo

rt1<-coredata(rt)
rt2<-index(rt)
df2<-data.frame(date=rt2,logret=rt1)
fit<-lm(rt2~rt1)
```

I converted to zoo to numeric to use "lm". I know there is tslm too but I am not sure how to use it here. 
My issue is that I am getting residuals in date format and I am sure it is because I converted the zoo series to numeric format.
How do i avoid this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Postings to SO should be **minimal** and you should definitely NOT post dangerous code like `rm` commands and superfluous stuff like the `cat` line and numerous library statements which are not used.  See [mcve].

Comment: I hope that is better for you now

Comment: It is no longer complete because the `library` statements needed to run the code are missing.

Answer (score 0):

The code simply extracts the index from the zoo object but does not convert the dates to numeric.  To do that:

```
rt2 <- as.numeric(rt2)
```